# How to use GParted for drivers with data

Tags: installation, partitioning, hard-drive

I would like to install Ubuntu on my 640 GB external hard drive.But about 100 gb of its capacity was already used. I heard there is a program called Gparted so I can creat some partition for Ubuntu installation files on my external disk.But can I use this program on Live-USB Ubuntu.

do you know a link how to use the program for this kind of situations

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well, resizing partitions with Gparted is really easy. You just select any partition you like and then give it a new size! And according to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/5912/if-i-resize-a-linux-partition-using-gparted-will-my-data-be-safe)  you will not loose any data. For more info got to this [wiki](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Gparted). If you have a live usb of ubuntu then it has already Gparted with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a live USB, here is the website

http://gparted.sourceforge.net/liveusb.php